# Logging in grails for specific controller

Tags: logging, grails, log4j

I have this code in my Config.groovy:

```
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%c{2} %m%n")
    }

    root {
        warn 'stdout'
    }
```

Now I want to log messages with DEBUG level from a specific controller (or specific package). How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your controller name is `ExampleController` in the `com.example` package, add this to the log4j closure in your `Config.groovy`:

```
debug 'grails.app.controllers.com.example.ExampleController'
```

See the Grails user guide for more [logging examples](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging).

Comment: I forgot the 'grails.app' part. Thanks.

Comment: I believe that it's actually 'grails.app.controllers.com.example.ExampleController' (notice the 's' in 'controllers'. At least that's what made it work for me in Grails 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
debug "grails.app.controller.your.package.YourController"
```

I'm assuming you're using grails 1.3.X. There was a difference in 1.0.X versions of grails.

Comment: As noted previously, it's "app.controllers", not "app.controller".  See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging

Comment: @MikeC I think that change happened between 1.3.x and 2.x.y